# Having an issue where values are not being sent through socket.io correctly, using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I am having an issue where I can't seem to keep values in tact throughout a function. Like if I do something like this:

```
console.log(object.maxhp)
console.log(object)
```

It will show the the maxhp property value, however the second console.log will not even show it.

Here is the main function for it:

```
const loadUp = async args => {
  let c, t, q;
  c = "User";
  t = "findById";
  q = [args.id];
  let user = await query(c, t, q);
  user.toObject();
  statHandler(user);
  addSnapShot(args.id, user);
  console.log(user.maxhp);
  console.log(user);
  c = "Area";
  t = "findOne";
  q = [{ name: user.location.area }];
  let ml = await query(c, t, q);
  Object.assign(user, { mobs: ml });
  c = "User";
  t = "updateOne";
  q = [{ _id: args.id }, { $set: { online: true } }];
  query(c, t, q);
  return await user;
};
```

Here is the query function:

```
const q = async (c, t, q) => {
  c = require(`../models/${c}`);
  let query = c[t](q[0], q[1]);
  return await query.exec().then(res => {
    return res;
  });
};

module.exports = q;
```

(I have it as query() in importing it)

So basically, the stathandler is supposed to add and modify a lot of information in the user object and update it. The snapshot somehow has these values correct (but I can see them when console.log(user), but can if i specify them `user.maxhp` for example).

However, it seems to lose those values when I send them to the client. I had this working before I went over to my new query function, and I have no idea why that's the reason it broke.

(I won't bother posting the stathandler function as its extremely long, and I know that part of it works, as i hadn't changed anything in that particular function)

I'm pretty sure its the way I am handling the query, but I can't for the life of me figure out what exactly is messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my query function to this; the `.lean()` was the answer, the other edits were just preference.

UPDATE: Better code by: jfriend00

```
const q = async (c, t, q) => {
  c = require(`../models/${c}`);
  let query = c[t](q[0], q[1]);
  return query.lean().exec()
};
```

As for the `.lean()` call will cause issues, I have no idea yet. But it seems to have worked on all the issues I had in a lot of situations.

Comment: Why are you doing `.then(res => {
      return res;
    });`?  That's a no-op - accomplishes nothing.  And, why are you doing `return await results` instead of `return results`.  The `await` there also does nothing.

Comment: When i remove the .then(), it returns absolutely nothing. Oh, that await is useless, woops lol

Comment: And, while you're at it, you may as well just do `return query().lean().exec();`  No need for the `await` there either.

Comment: Hmmm, When I firest did this, all that didn't work, but I guess when I changed everything everything seemed to fall in place and now I can do it like that, what? Ah oh well.

Comment: It also does not need to be `async` any more since there is no use of `await` and not using any of the other features of `async` functions.

Comment: Personally, I don't like single letter variables or argument names except for obvious things like loop indexes because they don't tell any reader of your code what those variables represent.  It's also very odd to reassign `c` from one thing to another here.  Use a new variable for the result of the `require()`.  There are no points for reusing variables for different things to save declaring an appropriately named variable.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but this is how I like to do things when I am the only one working on the code. It keeps it nice and neat in my opinion. I tend to dislike variables more than 5 characters long. If I know someone will be developing with me I will try to make them a bit more informational though. It is just easier for me to read, weirdly enough.